# Why do we use @html.action(string,object)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I really don't understand the usage of `Html.Action(string,object)` its return type is HTMl string so why do we even need it? and whats its relation with partialviewresult ? I have seen some people using `@html.action(String actionname,Object routeobject);` in any of their view and controller invoked by this method returns a partialviewresult whats that ?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: I understand that thanks for notifying anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **HtmlString** represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again. [HtmlString Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

There is a answer that I believe is good from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction) question:

`@Html.Action` and `@Html.RenderAction` are used when your partial view model are independent from parent model, basically it is used when you want to display any widget type content on page. You must create an action method which returns a partial view result while calling the method from view.

More, use **Html.Action** when you actually need to retrieve additional data from the server to populate the partial view

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457.aspx) for more detailed information.

More questions about the same topic:

[How can I use Html.Action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874775/how-can-i-use-html-action)

[MVC Html.Partial or Html.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766554/mvc-html-partial-or-html-action)

Maybe a bit of research before posting a question would be better