# Calling a controller method with bool return type from _layout page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a method in a controller which return a bool and I would like to use the value in _Layout.cshtml and based on the returned value, would like to redirect to a different action

```
        [HttpGet]
        public bool CheckPagePermission(PagePermissionDto pagePermission)
        {
            var claimsIdentity = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var userName = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("email")?.Value;
            pagePermission.UserName = userName;

            bool authorizedUser = _uow.PagePermissions.CheckPagePermission(pagePermission);
            return authorizedUser;
          }
```

now, I would like to check the above value and redirect to error page if false from _Layout.cshtml in head tag

Comment: I guess you simply need [`Html.Action`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874775/how-can-i-use-html-action)

Comment: Why aren't you writing an action filter for this?

Comment: @Fran I could but wasn't sure what to return when the authorizedUser is true as I don't want to take any action if its true

Comment: you don't want to take any action or you want the action to complete as normal if the user is authorized?

Comment: @Fran I want the action to complete normal as if the user is browsing from one page to other unless he/she is not authorized at which case, will be redirected to a error page

Comment: Are you using claims?  Are your public controller actions decorated with ClaimsPrincipalPermission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused because it seems like you are mixing claims and traditional authorization techniques.  I would think you could just use the ClaimsTranformer and subclass the ClaimsAuthorizationManager. but if this is something different and you want something easy, then maybe you want a custom authorization attribute

you could do something like this

```
public class MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var userName = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("email")?.Value;

        return _uow.PagePermissions.CheckPagePermission(new pagePermission { /*whatever you are passing here.*/ });
    }
}
```

Great information [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-authentication-customizing-authentication-and-authorization-the-right-way)