# MVC 5 PartialVIew is loading in Different Page

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel, partial-views

Overview:

I am essentially building a single page application. Three inputs and two tables that load based on the inputs' data.

Each table is set to a tab and each tab has a button to load their respective table's data. One table is set in a partial view. I'm trying this out to see if it works so I can set both of the tables to a partial view.

Problem: 
The partialview is loading the table into a new window when I click the submit button.

Example:
So, upon loading the web application, for example, 'http://localhost:30000/CommissionDatas/' the Index page  loads the page and the empty tables just fine.

I am using a ViewModel because each table uses a different model and I will get  an error about the Partial view table having a different data model.

Once I click the button "gpmbutton", for the partial view table,  the  buttion uses the  'formmethod' attribute to call actionresult method '_TrueUp'  and it will retrieve the data and return the  data model to the partial view. But, the partial view's table and it's data ends up posting the to  'http://localhost:30000/CommissionDatas/_TrueUp', which is a completely new page.

I have already tried changing the actionresult method  type to PartialViewResult and changing the return type from  'PartialView()' to a 'View' in the controller and that still did not work. I've also tried using @Partial in the index page as well as @RenderPartial for the partial view and I get the same result.

Also, both the 'Index' and the '_TrueUp' PartialView page are in the same folder under 'CommissionDatas' in the views folder.

Please HELP!

P.S. I removed the code that is not essential to the problem as the data is sensitive.

```
Index.cshtml
-------------------------------------------------------------
@model CommissionReport.Models.ViewModels.CommissionViewModel
@{
   Layout = null;
 }

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="submit" ID="commissionbutton" 
      formaction="ReturnCommissionData" 
      formmethod="post" 
    />   

    @if (Model != null)
    {
    <table id="mainTable" class="ui striped selectable table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       @foreach (var item in Model.CommissionData)
         {
            <tr>
            </tr>
         }
      </tbody>

    </table>
    }

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ID="gpmbutton" 
      formaction="_TrueUp" formmethod="post" 
    />

    <div>
       @if (Model != null)
       {
          Html.RenderPartial("_TrueUp");
       }
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

## This is the Partial View

```
_TrueUp.cshtml
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
@model CommissionReport.Models.ViewModels.CommissionViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
    var trueupmodel = Model.TrueUp;
}

    @if (Model != null)
    {
    <table id="mainTable" class="ui striped selectable table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       @foreach (var item in Model.TrueUp)
         {
            <tr>
            </tr>
         }
      </tbody>

    </table>
    }
```

## This is the Controller.

```
private CommissionViewModel vm = new CommissionViewModel();

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReturnCommissionData(FormReturn form)
{
        //Code to return data here

        vm.CommissionData = db.CommissionDatas.ToList();
        return View("Index", vm);

}

<HttpPost>
public ActionResult _TrueUp(FormReturn form)
{

    //Code For Data to be returned here
    vm.TrueUp = model;

    return PartialView("_TrueUp", vm);

 }
```

Comment: I tried my best to understand what's going on here and what the real issue is. But I couldn't figure it out. Try building you FormAction propperty from @Url.Action([action], [controller]) code to get the right relative url to the right action method.

Comment: Is it my description throwing you off?

Answer (score -1):

Please try @Html.Action("yourAction", "yourController") instead of @Html.RenderPartial("_TrueUp").

For further information visit:
[How can I use Html.Action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874775/how-can-i-use-html-action)
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_ChildActionExtensions_Action_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_)

EDIT:

Use: @Html.Partial("partialViewName", partialViewModel) partialViewModel is optional.
In your case: @Html.Partial("_TrueUp").