# How to call a controller from a view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Im using MVC and Im having the following html code to get data from mssql.

In the following code it calls the DebitAndCreditNotesService and the function GetCheckoutRoomInfo

`@Html.Partial("_InHouse", new DebitAndCreditNotesService().GetCheckoutRoomInfo())`

But how can i modify the above code to call a controller and function it got.
Suppose i got a controller and method for eg- CreditNoteController and the method is Inhouse

```
public class CreditNotesController : BaseController
{
public PartialViewResult InHouse()
        {

        }
}
```

How can i do this?
Im still a beginner

Comment: `@Html.Action(actionName, controllerName)`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn202741(v%3Dvs.118)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874775/how-can-i-use-html-action

Comment: You can also use <a> tag with 'asp-action' attribute

Answer (score -1):

I don't know your model structure, but;

```
public PartialViewResult InHouse()
{
CheckoutRoom model = new CheckoutRoom();
return View(model);
}
```

you can do it with a similar code.